# Deep freeze is disabling windows update

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates, deep-freeze

I have a  system using windows 7 64-Bit. While windows was updating deep freeze was active. After updating windows restarted so the update was removed. After the restart windows was stuck in this process and same process kept repeating so login page never shows up. I was wondering if there is a way to disble deep freeze from registry and login to my account. I tried booting the windows in safe mode but it didn't seem working! I'd be thankful if you help me

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows installation seem to have been damaged.
Below are some possible solutions.

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> during boot, and in *Advanced Boot Options > Repair Your Computer*
you could try these options in order:

- Startup Repair
- System Restore (to a restore point from before the problem)
- Last Known Good Configuration (advanced)

If none of these repair options work for, you might need to reinstall Windows.